# Matrix operations-Matrix multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Does matrix multiplication count as composition of functions? During the lecture, the lecturer mentioned that functions can be represented as a matrix, and multiplication between functions is defined as composition of functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does. It is actually a matter of points of view. Indeed, on one hand, a matrix $A$ is a linear map acting on a vector space $V$, so that $A : V \to V, v \mapsto A(v) := Av$ can be seen as a function on that space. On the other hand, such matrices are themselves the elements of a ring equipped with a multiplicative operation by definition. From the previous point of view, multiplication acts as a composition of linear maps, because $(A \circ B)(v) = A(B(v)) = A(Bv) = ABv = (AB)(v)$, hence $A \circ B = AB$.